# What's the origin of "さ", the nonsubjective (dunno how to call it nominalizer)

Tags: verbs, etymology, adjectives, suffixes, nominalization

So, I know that the subjective nominalizer み comes from the imperfective/irrealis form of む, apparently the subjective particle that makes things into subjective verbs?? I just heard this on a website. But if that exists... Then what does さ come from? Unless it doesn't have an origin. My closest guess is the su in suru but it doesn't really make any sense.

Comment: The auxiliary verb suffix ～む appears to be the same thing (derivationally, at least) as the volitional / suppositional / hortative suffix ～む that turned into the common _-ō_ ending in modern Japanese. The underlying sense seems to be _"seems like, looks like"_. I suspect this is ultimately the same root as in 目【め】 and 見【み】る.

Comment: In Old Japanese, we do see examples of noun formation via verbs taking the _-a_ ending, such as 塚【つか】 ("hill, mound") from verb 築【つ】く ("to build up into a structure"). I wonder if the _"objective amount or degree"_ nominalizing suffix ～さ for adjectives might be a similar kind of shift from the adjective terminal ending ～し? This is purely speculative, and I am uncertain if any academic author might have explored this possibility.

Comment: oh i didnt know that its the same as the volitional!

Comment: well there might not be an answer

Comment: Digging around in the 日本国語大辞典【にほんこくごだいじてん】 (NKD) entry for [suffix ～さ](https://kotobank.jp/word/%E3%81%95-506834) (search or scroll to the section marked 〘接尾〙), I see in sense [三] that this might be related to the さ in さま ("resemblance, way, likeness"), which suggests a connection to さ ("like that, in that way"), precursor to modern そう. However, I don't see anything in that entry that explicitly says this. The Kotobank version of the NKD is abridged, however -- I wonder if someone with access to a fuller version of the NKD might find additional details?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @EiríkrÚtlendi suggests, 日本国語大辞典 contains a more explicit entry on the etymology, but essentially the same:

> サマ（様）の反〔[名語記](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E5%90%8D%E8%AA%9E%E8%A8%98)・[大言海](https://kotobank.jp/word/%E5%A4%A7%E8%A8%80%E6%B5%B7-91059)〕

反 should mean 略 ([source](https://kotobank.jp/word/%E5%8F%8D-563548))

Comment: Dang I was thinking about that and I didn't approve it until I was browsing my posts... Atleast i didnt see it and thought about it before so I can say I knew it... But now I am curious about ら や and か but they probably don't have a  由来